# How do I install Ubuntu SDK IDE

Tags: sdk

[image]

[image]

How can I install Ubuntu SDK IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you post seems very old, and the PPA hasn't been updated in over 6 years.

Also, there's nothing called Ubuntu Phone anymore, this was announced in 2014. It seems you're

There is no current package called [Ubuntu SDK](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-sdk).

There is [Android SDK](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=android-sdk) from the Universe repository.